# How to do a count of fields in SQL with wrong datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to import legacy data from another system into our system.  The problem I am having is that the legacy data is dirty- very dirty!  We have a field which should be an integer, but sometimes is a varchar, and the field is defined as a varchar...

In SQL Server, how can I do a select to show those records where the data is varchar instead if int?

Thanks

Comment: Fields? I don't think you can cause _there is no fields in databases_ there is only **Columns and Rows**

Comment: A field is a row/column specific reference.  If you prefer other terminology, great, it doesn't change what is being asked

Comment: Thumbs up, @Sami.

Comment: Find all varchar fields in database and run try_cast over all rows in all tables. If ALL conversions pass for a column in a table proceed with alter table.

Comment: In SQL a field as a part of the record data type.

Comment: @jarlh - `ISNUMERIC`? The function that answers a question nobody wants to ask? If they want an `int` then (modern) `try_cast` and `null` check or the older double-negative `LIKE` expression checking for only digits would be better suggestions.

Comment: @jarlh Oh man I don't think so `SELECT ISNUMERIC('+')`

Comment: Works perfectly  Use "where isnumeric(columnname) = 0" to fid those with incorrect values

Comment: Don't listen to my advice above (now removed), I've never used SQL Server...

Comment: Your advice was perfect and worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find rows<sup>1</sup> where a column contains any non-digit characters or is longer than 9 characters (either condition means that we cannot assume it would fit in an `int`, use something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE LEN(ColumnName) > 9 or ColumnName LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

Not that there's a negative in the `LIKE` condition - we're trying to find a string that contains at least one *non-digit* character.

A more modern approach would be to use `TRY_CAST` or `TRY_CONVERT`. But note that a failed conversion returns `NULL` and `NULL` is perfectly valid for an `int`!

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ColumnName is not null and try_cast(ColumnName as int) is null
```

---

`ISNUMERIC` isn't appropriate. It answers a question nobody has ever wanted to ask (IMO) - "Can this string be converted to *any* of the numeric data types (I don't care which ones and I don't want you to tell me which ones either)?"

`ISNUMERIC('$,,,,,,,.')` is `1`. That should tell you all you need to know about this function.

---

<sup>1</sup>If you just want a count, as per the title of the question, then substitute `COUNT(*)` for `*`.

Comment: I was not checking for length, just whether it was integer, something is numeric() did perfectly

Comment: The first query will return (eg: `-11`)

Comment: @MarcL - Yes, but `isnumeric` tells you that a string can be converted to *any* of the numeric data types. It doesn't tell you, specifically, if the string can be converted to any of the integer data types (or `int` specifically)

Comment: I see your point, but at a gross level to tell the customer they have a massive data issue it wors (when there are 3,8 million records and 1,6 million of them have a character in an integer field, it is more than a minor problem...)

Comment: @MarcL - yes, but things like `12d4` are numeric as per `isnumeric` and surely you want to report on those values too. My pet "quintessentially bad" example is `ISNUMERIC('$,,,,,,,.')`.

Answer (score 2):

> In SQL Server, how can I do a select to show those records where the data is varchar instead of int?

I would do it like

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
  Data VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
('102'),
(NULL),
('11Blah'),
('5'),
('Unknown'),
('1ThinkPad123'),
('-11');

SELECT Data -- Per the title COUNT(Data)
FROM
(
  SELECT Data, 
         cast('' as xml).value('sql:column("Data") cast as xs:int ?','int') Result
  FROM T --You can add WHERE Data IS NOT NULL to exclude NULLs
) TT
WHERE Result IS NULL;
```

**Returns:**

```
+----+--------------+
|    |     Data     |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | NULL         |
|  2 | 11Blah       |
|  3 | Unknown      |
|  4 | 1ThinkPad123 |
+----+--------------+
```

That if you can't use **[`TRY_CAST()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** function, if you are working on 2012+ version, I'll recommend that you use `TRY_CAST()` function like

```
SELECT Data
FROM T
WHERE Data IS NOT NULL 
      AND 
      TRY_CAST(Data AS INT) IS NULL;
```

**[Demo](https://rextester.com/OIUOY15183)**

---

Finally, I would say do not use [`ISNUMERIC()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function because of (from docs) ...

**Note**

> ISNUMERIC returns 1 for some characters that are not numbers, such as plus (+), minus (-), and valid currency symbols such as the dollar sign ($). For a complete list of currency symbols, see [money and smallmoney (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/money-and-smallmoney-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Your `like` expression isn't working how you think. E.g. it doesn't report `1b2bc`. `^` has special meaning as the first character inside the `[]` brackets. Of course, if you then move the `-` you'll see it's working the opposite way so you need to remove the `not` outside. But then it starts accepting `-`s in any position (and multiple instances of it too)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yup, I think about it just right now, since it can be any value